# EntityCommandExecutionException with EF 6 in project net 4.0?

Tags: entity-framework

I have using entity framework 6 in a project that is net 4.0, and when I instaled the nuget package, the project adds the reference to EntityFramework.dll and EntityFrameWork.SqlServer.dll.

However, I want to capture the exception EntityCommandExecutionException, but there is not avaliable in neither of the both dlls.

I know that I can add a reference to System.Data.Entity, but I don't konw if this a good solution, because when I try to use the enum EntityState there are a conflict because the are one in the System.Data.Entity and other in EntityFramework.dll.

So the quiestion is if it is a good idea to use the System.Data.Entity library with EF 6. And if it is a bad idea, which is the equivalent exception of EntityCommandExecutionException in EF 6?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF6 does not use System.Data.Entity.dll so adding a reference to this assembly won't help since EF6 will throw its own `EntityCommandExecutionException`. Actually adding a reference to an EF6 project will create even more confusion since the two are not designed to work together even though the type names tend to be called the same (EF6 was build by merging System.Data.Entity.dll and EntityFramework.dll code bases but is not binary compatible with EF5). In your app you need add

using System.Data.Entity.Core;

since this is where the [EntityCommandExecutionException type lives in EF6](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework/Core/EntityCommandExecutionException.cs).